# Migrate AngularJS Directive to Angular 2.x+ Directive as HTML decorator

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, typescript

Is it effectively no longer possible to use Angular directives as an "HTML decorator" as I've taken to calling them?

I found this pattern invaluable in Angular 1.x for migrating legacy applications to Single Page Apps by first building a set of directives that would add functionality to markup generated by the server.  It seems like an oversight for the Angular Team to eliminate that functionality.

A Contrived Example:

There is a jQuery plugin for prettier select boxes called chosen.  In 1.x I would do the following on a page that was returned from the server.

HTML:

```
<select chosen-select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
app.directive('chosenSelect', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                $(element).chosen();
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

This would execute the chosen plugin on the HTML generated by the server and I didn't need any real changes to my pages other than defining an ng-app.  Can this style of directive no longer be done using Angular 2+?

Thanks

Comment: your question makes no sense. revise the post

Comment: @Aravind It makes perfect sense to me.  Can you write a directive that binds to server side markup on page load.  I used to use the same pattern all the time.  It made adding interactivity to legacy apps very easy without having to rewrite the whole application. Insofar as I can tell, this method of using directives doesn't work with the new Angular design.  It essentially made angular useless to me on existing, no SPA applications and I abandoned angular in favor of Vue.

Comment: @Peter what you infer from the post. answer -- angular and post is in angularjs what you understood?

Comment: @Aravind your comment makes no sense. revise your comment

Comment: @georgeawg which comment you are mentioning?

Comment: @Aravind He's giving an example of how he would write an HTML decorator in AngularJS, and asking if this is doable in Angular 2+.  It doesn't do to bother writing an Angular Directive because I've done it and as far as I can tell it only works with Component templates and not server generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({selector: '[promoChosenSelect]'})
export class ChosenSelectDirective  implements OnInit{
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).chosen();
  }
```

}

in module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    ChosenSelectDirective
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClickOutsideDirective,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: []
 })
 export class SharedModule {
 }
```

and here html:

```
 <select promoChosenSelect>
    <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: That method works if I'm using a component with a template, but it throws an error that my directive cannot be used as an entry component if I attempt to use it without being attached to a component.